# No puedo probar la aplicacion en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

me pasa que cuando doy click en el boton Run para probar la aplicacion no me aparece nada 
[image]

pero no me aparece nada se supone que siempre me sale esta ventana cuando corro mis proyectos, pero especificamente en el proyecto en el que estoy no me aparece esta ventana ni nada tampoco ni un mensaje de error ni nada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedo hacer? porque no puedo correr la app de ese proyecto?

Comment: has probado a crear nuevos virtual devices? o conectar tu movil para ver si detecta tu movil?genimotion no usas no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin soporte de VT-x y SVM en tu procesadora te conviene siempre correr la aplicación en un dispositivo real (en tu caso el Sony D5306).

Para hacer eso funcionar, asegúrate de lo siguiente:

- Tu dispositivo esta conectado por cable USB
- Tu dispositivo tiene modo de depuración activado (configuración-> opciónes de desarrollador)
- Tu dispositivo se encuentra conectado como **Almacenamiento USB** (no MTP ni PTP)

Si revisaste en tu dispositivo que cumples con todos estos condiciónes, revisa la configuración en Android Studio:

- Revisa *Run->Edit Configurations->Android App->app*
- En la pestaña *General* elige en la opción *Target* "Open ... Target Dialog" o "USB Device"
- Asegúrate que "Use same device for duture launches" esta **desmarcado**

Así se te debería abrir el dialogo cuando apretas el símbolo de depuración.

Revisa bien lo se que te dice abajo en tu Android Studio SDK cuando lo haces. Tomando en cuenta que tu procesadora no tiene soporte para virtualisación lo hace probable que no trabajas en un sistema con tremendo rendimiento. Esp puede significar que el *build* toma su bien tiempo a ratos, especialmente si no tienes muy amplia memoria a tu disposición. Puede ser que vas a tener algunos minutos de paciencia para el build, pero Android Studio te debería informar sobre lo que esta pasando por mientras.

Si estos pasos no te resuelven el problema, revisa lo que te sale en el *Event Log* cuando arrancas la depuración.

Answer (score 0):

Solo instala HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager)

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement

instrucciones:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows